# How To Make Facebook Comments Appear On Site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've successfully added Facebook comments on my site, but it's not quite how I wanted it to be. My site's FB comments remain on my site and aren't connected to FB and vice versa.

Is there some code missing? I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyb0m.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Comments mirroring - https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments/ ?
That isn't available broadly yet, please sign up to receive updates.